# Deserializing duplicate XML elements with unique attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Response>
  <Value Name="ID">1</Value>
  <Value Name="User">JSmith</Value>
  <Value Name="Description">Testing 123</Value>
</Response>
```

How can I deserialize this so that the value names are properties on the class, and the text values are the values of the properties?

Note that the value names never change, so `Name="ID"` will always exist, for example.

Here is my class so far:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Response")]
public class ReportingResponse
{
    // [What goes here?]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    // [...]
    public string User { get; set; }

    // [...]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Is that correct?

Comment: @dbc Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That XML is structured as a collection of name/value pairs rather than as a class with predefined properties, and it would be easier and more natural to deserialize it as such.

If you're determined to deserialize into a class, assuming you're using [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you could introduce a proxy array of name/value pairs for that purpose, like so:

```
public class NameValuePair
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name={0}, Value=\"{1}\"", Name, Value);
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Response")]
public class ReportingResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Value")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public NameValuePair[] XmlNameValuePairs
    {
        get
        {
            return NameValuePairExtensions.GetNamedValues(this).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            NameValuePairExtensions.SetNamedValues(this, value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And then some reflection to automatically load up the array:

```
public static class NameValuePairExtensions
{
    public static List<NameValuePair> GetNamedValues<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        List<NameValuePair> list = new List<NameValuePair>();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var getter = prop.GetGetMethod();
                var setter = prop.GetSetMethod();

                if (getter != null && setter != null) // Confirm this property has public getters & setters.
                {
                    list.Add(new NameValuePair() { Name = prop.Name, Value = (string)getter.Invoke(obj, null) });
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void SetNamedValues<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<NameValuePair> values)
    {
        if (obj == null || values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(value.Name);
            if (prop == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("No public property found for {0}", value));
                continue;
            }
            try
            {
                prop.SetValue(obj, value.Value, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception setting " + value.ToString() + " : \n" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fills the array with all string-valued property names and values.  You might want something more intelligent, in which case manually filling the array, labeling properties with a custom attribute indicating those to be exported, or whatever, might be more appropriate.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured was the case. Thanks. This works, however, I think an easier way (at least for my implementation) is to just create a "Value" class, store the results in an array, and then have the Getter of the property reference into the array using Linq (e.g. `public string ID { get { return myValues.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == "ID"); } }`).

Comment: [XmlText] was the key to solving my problem. This is what lets you put a value in an element without having that variable name become a new element.