# Deserializing XML where elements and attributes have duplicate names

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to Deserialize the following XML. Problem is the duplicate element names and attribute names. I have tried this apporach 
[Deserializing duplicate XML elements with unique attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960542/deserializing-duplicate-xml-elements-with-unique-attributes)

But i keep getting.: "Account xmlns='' was not expected."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Account>
  <Field APIName="WrntyID">1234</Field>
  <Field APIName="ExternalID">4321</Field>
  <Field APIName="CreationDate">07/04/2015 18:28:45</Field>
  <Field APIName="Name"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Phone"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Mobile"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Fax"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Email"></Field>
  <Field APIName="GovID"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Note"></Field>
  <Field APIName="IsActive">True</Field>
  <Field APIName="ConnectedToSuperBiz">False</Field>
  <Field APIName="Street"></Field>
  <Field APIName="City"></Field>
  <Field APIName="State"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Country">USA</Field>
  <Field APIName="ZipCode">33172</Field>
  <Field APIName="Discount">0</Field>
  <Field APIName="PriceLevelName">USD</Field>
  <Field APIName="Prop1"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Prop2"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Prop3"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Prop4"></Field>
  <Field APIName="Prop5"></Field>
  <Agents>
    <Agent>
      <Field APIName="WrntyID">54321</Field>
      <Field APIName="ExternalID"></Field>
    </Agent>
  </Agents>
  <Catalogs>
    <Catalog>
      <Field APIName="WrntyID">12345</Field>
      <Field APIName="ExternalID"></Field>
    </Catalog>
  </Catalogs>
  <Locations>
    <Location>
      <Field APIName="WrntyID">123456</Field>
      <Field APIName="ExternalID">0002</Field>
    </Location>
  </Locations>
  <Contacts>
    <Contact>
      <Field APIName="WrntyID">1234</Field>
      <Field APIName="ExternalID"></Field>
    </Contact>
  </Contacts>
</Account>
```

My C# classes look like this now.:

```
[XmlRoot]
    public class Account {        
        public Agents Agents { get; set; }
        public Catalogs Catalogs { get; set; }
        public Locations Locations { get; set; }
        public Contacts Contacts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Agents {
        [XmlArray("Agent")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Values))]
        public Values[] Field { get; set; }
    }
    public class Catalogs {
        [XmlArray("Catalog")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Values))]
        public Values[] Field { get; set; }
    }
    public class Contacts {
        [XmlArray("Contact")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Values))]
        public Values[] Field { get; set; }
    }
    public class Locations {
        [XmlArray("Location")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Values))]
        public Values[] Field { get; set; }
    }
    public class Values {
        [XmlAttribute("APIName")]
        public string APIName { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

(I have ommited some of the classes for readability sake)
The big question is this, is there a different way of Deserializing to C# obj or would the proper approach be to do the mapping manually?

**EDIT** 
Added a revised Class structure, can anyone help me on how to structure the classes? Not sure on how to handle all the the Field=APIName elements in Account?

Comment: I would suggest creating a class in code that represents in the XML above. Once you have done this use the XML serializer and have a look at the XML that is produced. You will then what the XML *should* look like? I doubt it will look as neat as what you've provided.

Comment: Creating a class that represents the XML is part of the problem. Not entirely sure how to handle the Field elements.

Comment: I would suggest creating a Collection/List/Array called Fields. You'd need one of these within Account, one within Agent and one within Catalog. But to get that to serialize to/deserialize from the XML you've give you'll need to customize the serialization/deserialization yourself. There are plenty of example of this online.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a [Namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) in your XML file.

[XmlRootAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defaults to: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` if no custom namespace is provided.

Try telling your `XmlReader` not to use Namespaces

```
 XmlReader reader = new XmlReader() { Namespaces = false };
```

**BUT**: I strongly recommend using specific namespaces for your files!

Comment: I have no control over the files that i have to read, i basicly only get the folder location, then have to read all the xml files in them. And it works, except for this Account XML file because i cant deserialize it, because i cant structure my C# classes correctly.